# Slide in and out a component with Angular animations

Tags: angular, angular-animations

Using Angular 6 and `@angular/animations` module, I'm trying to implement a custom sidenav element that must slide in and out smoothly from the main page by clicking a button.

As you can see [here](https://slide-demo.stackblitz.io) this element hides to the left smoothly, but not the other way, where it just dissapears.

Here is the code for the animation:

```
animations: [
    trigger('slideMenu', [
      state('false', style({
        transform: 'translateX(-250px)'
      })),
      state('true', style({
        transform: 'translateX(0)'
      })),
      transition('true <=> false', animate('400ms ease-in-out'))
    ])
  ]
```

The full project can be seen in https://stackblitz.com/edit/slide-demo.

How could I make the component to slide to both directions correctly?

**Edit**
Relevant html using the component:

```
<app-home-sidenav [@slideMenu]="isVisible ? true : false" [hidden]="!isVisible"></app-home-sidenav>  
  <div class="home-content">
    <div class="home-label">
      <span>This content should expand upon hiding sidenav</span>
    </div>
    <button (click)="onToggle()">
    Toggle Sidenav
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because you are using `[hidden]="!isVisible"` in your component which is evaluated without any delay and hide the sidebar before the animation.
If you remove the `[hidden]` attribute and set your 'false' state like this it will get you in the right way:

```
state('false', style({
    transform: 'translateX(-250px)',
    display: 'none'
}))
```

But as far as I can tell you will need another animation if you want the main content to spread together with the sidebar.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I will look forward for a solution for the main component.